# PHP Uploader - Problems with UploadDir option

Tags: php, jquery

Hi everyone and thanks in advance for your support ;)

Im using the plugin https://github.com/CreativeDream/jQuery.filer, for PHP Uploader, and in /php/class.uploader.php im trying to change the upload dir in the function below:

```
    private function initialize($field, $options){
        if(is_array($field) && in_array($field, $_FILES)){
            $this->field = $field;
            $this->field['Field_Name'] = array_search($field, $_FILES);
            $this->field['Field_Type'] = 'input';

            if(!is_array($this->field['name'])){
            $this->field = array_merge($this->field, array("name" => array($this->field['name']), "tmp_name"=>array($this->field['tmp_name']), "type"=>array($this->field['type']), "error"=>array($this->field['error']), "size"=>array($this->field['size'])));
            }

            foreach($this->field['name'] as $key=>$value){ if(empty($value)){ unset($this->field['name'][$key]); unset($this->field['type'][$key]); unset($this->field['tmp_name'][$key]); unset($this->field['error'][$key]); unset($this->field['size'][$key]); } }

            $this->field['length'] = count($this->field['name']);
        }elseif(is_string($field) && $this->isURL($field)){
            $this->field = array("name" => array($field), "size"=>array(), "type"=>array(), "error"=>array());
            $this->field['Field_Type'] = 'link';
            $this->field['length'] = 1;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

        if($options != null){
            $this->setOptions($options);
        }
        $varuser='test';
        //$varuser=$_SESSION['username'];
        $this->options['uploadDir']="../../../uploads/".$varuser."/";

        return $this->prepareFiles();
    }
```

As you can see, at the end of the function i'm setting the "option" UploadDir like a concat of "../../../uploads/" + $varuser +"/", and using the current definition of $varuser($varuser='test') everything works.

But, my problem start when i try to assign to $varuser my session username variable, i receive an error in the custom.js:91 (/examples/dragdrop/js)

Please, any idea of what is happening?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Can you show us the error?

Comment: Sure! This is the error that i get in debugger mode (Chrome):
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (custom.js:91)
    at Object.success (jquery.filer.js:610)
    at i (jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.1.0.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.1.0.min.js:4)

Do you need extra info? Let me know ;)